# Umbraco 4 Document Type not showing on page

Tags: umbraco

I am a newbie with Umbraco so please excuse if I am missing something obvious. I have trawled the internet, but I can't find a solution to my problem.

I am mainly using the Umbraco.TV videos to guide me through this, and in particularly, this one: http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/umbraco-fundamentals/datatypes/using-content-and-media-pickers/TVPlayer.

The others videos and tutorials successfully got me through setting up a responsive nav and sub-nav, but on this issue, I'm stuck.

I am building a site which requires multiple CTAs. The text for these need to be entered by persons who have no coding experience so I've set up Document Types containing RichText Editor fields for them to enter the required text and images.

Tab: Generic Properties

```
H2 (h2), Type: Richtext editor
Article Description (articleDescription), Type: Richtext editor
Article Feature Image (articleFeatureImage), Type: Media Picker
Label (label), Type: Label
```

In the Template I have then inserted an Umbraco page field which references the relevant Document Type:

```
<div class="rel-art">
<umbraco:Item field="relatedContent1" runat="server" />
</div>
```

However, when I view the page in a browser, all I'm getting on the page is the Document Type ID:

```
<div class="rel-art"> 1202 </div>
```

I have tried setting it up and inserting it as a xslt:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($currentPage/data [@alias = 'relatedContent1'])/@nodeName"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My "Visualise XSLT" button isn't working though so I don't know what is would say at this point. I don't get a modal window. (I'm working remotely onto my client's system so that may have an impact.)

Now, if I insert the accompanying Macro into my template:

```
<div class="rel-art">
<umbraco:Macro Alias="RelatedContent1" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
</div>
```

that results in not even the ID showing when I view the page:

```
    <div class="rel-art">  </div>
```

I have tried with and without @nodeName, but no difference.

What is happening? What am I doing wrong? The only thing I can think of is that I had some trouble getting another Document Type to show up on the page until I changed its only Property Type from RichText Editor to Textstring. But I tried that with this one as well, and that didn't make any difference.

I am using Umbraco v4.9, if that helps.

Any help is gratefully received!

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Trine,

It is not very clear, but I noticed that the returned value is ' 1202 ' (having spaces). Could you please check your code with a static value i.e.

```
<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById(1202)/@nodeName"/>
```

if this works fine, then the problem is your 'relatedContent1'. You can Trim its value and use it in GetXmlNodeById function.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you are trying to display an image chosen with a media picker. If this is the case then you should use the GetMedia method:

```
<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($currentPage/data[@alias='relatedContent1'], 'false')/data[@alias='umbracoFile']" />
```

Check out [How to use umbraco.library GetMedia in XSLT](http://leekelleher.com/2009/11/30/how-to-use-umbraco-library-getmedia-in-xslt/) by [Lee Kelleher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12787/leekelleher) for more details and for a more fool proof approach for getting media.